# Add the imageview as the header of the listview

Tags: android

Hi I am developing one app using the below link
[Custom ListView With Headers](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/)

Now My question is i want to set the image as header for the listview.I am display the list of items using the second type of addsection i.e;

```
adapter.addSection("Security", new SimpleAdapter(this, security, R.layout.list_complex,  
            new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));
```

I am using the image view instead of textview in list_headre.xml.at that time i got the following exception

```
02-28 05:43:12.273: ERROR/ArrayAdapter(1212): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
02-28 05:43:12.273: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1212): Shutting down VM
02-28 05:43:12.273: WARN/dalvikvm(1212): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
02-28 05:43:12.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at chronicle.books.shopping.SeparatedListAdapter.getView(SeparatedListAdapter.java:97)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1521)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1108)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:900)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
02-28 05:43:12.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
```

Now I want to display the image as header instead of TextView.For this please give me some code suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` only supports `TextView` views. [As per the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html): *To use something other than TextViews for the array display, for instance, ImageViews, or to have some of data besides toString() results fill the views, override getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to return the type of view you want.*

If you just want a single `ImageView` in the header, I would use my original answer below.

**Original answer**: Use the method [`addHeaderView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) in `ListView` and just pass in an `ImageView`.

Comment: I am taking the textview in headrefile.xml.I replced that with image at that time i got the force close regarding adapter.Please check once url what i am sending

Comment: I am not clear on what you are doing. If replacing a `TextView` with an `ImageView` is causing an exception, please post the exception. Also some code would be helpful because I don't know what this headrefile.xml file is.

Comment: I am already told that use the same code from that url i.e;http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/