# Sample code for custom listView with image headers

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i want sample code for custom listView with image headers .Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117540/add-the-imageview-as-the-header-of-the-listview)?

Comment: But i did not got the answer.in that question i got problem with some code.in this i want new sample code

Comment: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/ try this